# Redirecting to Instagram authorization URL from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a Divi theme module that's gonna display user's Instagram feed on a page. I need to redirect them to Instagram authorization URL. The divi module is a PHP file.

PHP function `header()` isn't working:
Warning:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:237)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\Divi-child\Modules\Instagram\init.php
>   on line 21

What different way can I use to redirect a user to this URL or am I approaching this all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = 'your_url';
</script>
<?php
```

or:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='your_url'</script>";
```

And at last:

```
$url = "your_url";
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $url . '">';
```

Where `0` is the number of seconds.